# Strict regex routing

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have been experimenting with Sinatra lately and I've been having some "problems" with regex-based routing... For example,

```
get "/something/" do
  status 400
end
```

matches `/something` but neither `/something/` nor `/somethingelse`. However,

```
get %r{/something/([0-9]{3})} do |number|
  status number
end
```

matches `/something/201` but also `/something/201/` and `something/201-and-somethingelse`. Perhaps I should rewrite the regex to read `%r{/something/([0-9]+)$}` but it doesn't make sense to me to include the dollar sign since this capture should be strict, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The question here is ambigous. Do you want the first example to match with and without a trailing slash, or do you want the second example to match only with a trailing slash?

Comment: I believe there's a typo in your question ("something/201-and-somethingelse" should have a "/" at the beginning) but only you can confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

Sinata is following the normal regex rules for Ruby. From an IRB session:

```
pattern = %r{/something/([0-9]{3})}
=> something[0-9]{3}
pattern.match "/something/201"
=> #<MatchData "/something/201" 1:"201">
pattern.match "/something/201/"
=> #<MatchData "/something/201" 1:"201">
pattern.match "something/201-and-somethingelse"
=> nil
pattern.match "/something/201-and-somethingelse"
=> #<MatchData "/something/201" 1:"201">
```

(this takes into account the typo I pointed out above).

Your other example of `get "/something/" do` is a string, not a regex, but certain patterns can be included as a convenience e.g. `?`. Therefore:

```
get "/something/" do # will match "/something/" but not "/something"
get "/something" do # will match "/something" but not "/something/"
get "/something/?" do # will match "/something" and "/something/"
```